# Clickhouse AggregateFunction(argMax,String,UInt32) fails with error java.io.IOException: AggregateFunction(argMax, String, UInt32) is not supported

Tags: clickhouse

I have created a clickhouse Aggregate table

```
CREATE TABLE top_user
(
    `type` FixedString(1),
    `id` UInt32,
    `product_name` String DEFAULT '' CODEC(ZSTD(3)),
    `start_of_hour` DateTime CODEC(DoubleDelta,ZSTD(1)),
    `max_user` AggregateFunction(argMax,String,UInt32),
    `count` AggregateFunction(sum,UInt32)
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
ORDER BY (`type`,
 id,
 product_name,
 start_of_hour)
```

and to load data to this from another table i use the following materialized view

```
Create MATERIALIZED VIEW top_user_mv to top_user AS 
select `type`
    ,id
    , product_name
    , start_of_hour
    , argMaxState(`user`,`count`) as max_user
    , sumState(`count`)
from user_counts 
group by (`type`,id,product_name,start_of_hour)
```

I get the following error

```
org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBCException: SQL Error: java.io.IOException: AggregateFunction(argMax, String, UInt32) is not supported
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCResultSetImpl.nextRow(JDBCResultSetImpl.java:183)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.fetchQueryData(SQLQueryJob.java:816)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:628)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.lambda$1(SQLQueryJob.java:487)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:173)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeSingleQuery(SQLQueryJob.java:494)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.extractData(SQLQueryJob.java:913)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor$QueryResultsContainer.readData(SQLEditor.java:3760)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:123)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:173)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:121)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetViewer$ResultSetDataPumpJob.run(ResultSetViewer.java:5033)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.io.IOException: AggregateFunction(argMax, String, UInt32) is not supported
    at com.clickhouse.jdbc.SqlExceptionUtils.create(SqlExceptionUtils.java:45)
    at com.clickhouse.jdbc.SqlExceptionUtils.handle(SqlExceptionUtils.java:90)
    at com.clickhouse.jdbc.ClickHouseResultSet.next(ClickHouseResultSet.java:716)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCResultSetImpl.next(JDBCResultSetImpl.java:272)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCResultSetImpl.nextRow(JDBCResultSetImpl.java:180)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: AggregateFunction(argMax, String, UInt32) is not supported
    at com.clickhouse.client.ClickHouseDeserializer.lambda$static$1(ClickHouseDeserializer.java:22)
    at com.clickhouse.client.data.ClickHouseRowBinaryProcessor$MappedFunctions.lambda$buildMappingsForAggregateFunctions$2(ClickHouseRowBinaryProcessor.java:188)
    at com.clickhouse.client.data.ClickHouseRowBinaryProcessor$MappedFunctions.deserialize(ClickHouseRowBinaryProcessor.java:466)
    at com.clickhouse.client.data.ClickHouseRowBinaryProcessor.readAndFill(ClickHouseRowBinaryProcessor.java:509)
    at com.clickhouse.client.ClickHouseDataProcessor.nextRecord(ClickHouseDataProcessor.java:147)
    at com.clickhouse.client.ClickHouseDataProcessor.access$100(ClickHouseDataProcessor.java:21)
    at com.clickhouse.client.ClickHouseDataProcessor$RecordsIterator.next(ClickHouseDataProcessor.java:36)
    at com.clickhouse.client.ClickHouseDataProcessor$RecordsIterator.next(ClickHouseDataProcessor.java:22)
    at com.clickhouse.jdbc.ClickHouseResultSet.next(ClickHouseResultSet.java:714)
    ... 15 more
```

I have tried several variations of the AggregateFunction but they all lead to the same error.

Comment: How are you querying `top_user`? Are you use a merge state function i.e. https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/combinators#-mergestate ? If you don't the aggregating states will be returned to the client - these arent supported by the Java client. Use a